# Benchmark for CSPRNG as stream ciphers?

Tags: aes, random-number-generator, stream-cipher, chacha, salsa20

My limitation in my security protocol is that I want my RNG as CSPRNG and I also want it to be super fast.

If I use Salsa20 or ChaCha or AES counter mode, I don't get the desired speed. I want my PRNG to work at the speed of 100 Gbps or more.

Morever, I need to be cryptographically secured.

Any suggestions regarding that? Do there exist such CSPRNG that can give me output stream at the speed of 100Gbps or above? Or in other words that can provide bit streams with a speed of 10^-11 bits per sec?

P.S: I don't care about the system requiremt, the platform could be FPGA, GPU etc, I just need some numbers to compare with and to know that with any kind of feasible platform (not super computers) can I achieve the target of 100Gbps in any of the CSPRNG?

Comment: Use parallel ChaCha20?

Comment: **The answer heavily depends on the platform you're targeting (Instruction Set, Microarchitecture, Frequency, whether you're willing to use multiple and how many cores, ...).** However, I find it odd that AES is not fast enough given that in counter mode with hardware support on x86, for details on why see my answer [on matter modeling on exactly this topic](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/1682/1128).

Answer (score 5):

The first thing to **NOTE** is that said by SEJPM in the comment, performance depends on the hardware - in both horizontal (core count, etc.) and vertical (clock speed, etc.) dimensions. The second thing to understand is that, although CSPRNGs and stream ciphers can share underlaying primitive, their security requirements are different.

So now, let's get started - what're some of the famous symmetric-key primitives?

There are 2 dimensions to consider when excluding the hardware parallism:

1. block size,
2. execution time per block.

Grades from slow to fast in: $$\text{Moderate} < \text{Fast} < \text{Very Fast} < \text{High} < \text{Very High}.$$ The grades are my personal opinion.

| Primitive | Block Size | SW Performance Grading | HW Performance Grading |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Gimli | 384-bit | Very High | Very High |
| Keccak-p[1600,24] | 1600-bit | Very Fast | High |
| Keccak-p[800,12] (not yet standardized) | 800-bit | High | High |
| AES-128 | 128-bit | High | Very High |
| ChaCha20 | 512-bit | High | High |

I haven't done systematic benchmarks on diverse hardwares and implementations yet, but the numbers are provided here for a quick reference. I used my own (hardly-optimized) [MySuiteA](https://github.com/dannyniu/MySuiteA) library with ad-hoc benchmarking code written in a rush.

| Primitive | Time of $2^{20}$ iterations of execution on Apple Silicon M1 |
| --- | --- |
| Gimli | 0.973sec |
| Keccak-p[1600,24] | 16.495sec |
| Keccak-p[800,12] (not yet standardized) | 8.143sec |
| AES-128 | 35.657sec(sw,unoptimized) 0.184sec(arm-neon-crypto) |
| ChaCha20 | 1.287sec |

Next, we can consider implementation side.

- **SBox** Modern cryptography wisdom says this: avoid SBox if it has to be implemented using look-up table (because it's a cache-memory side-channel), so AES is the most dangerous here;
- **Block Size** AES is also dangerous due to its small block size - 128-bit is too small a space for nonce and counter. ChaCha20 also has only 128-bit space for nonce and counter, but it has larger state and a side-channel-resistant non-linear layer.
- **ARX vs Binary Polynomial** ARX stands for Add-Rotate-Xor, which is a traditional paradigm for obtaining non-linearity (ChaCha20 follows this). It has the implementation disadvantage of requiring somewhat more complex circuit when doing a hardware implementation, and this is where ones without arithmetic addition - those based on binary polynomials have a win (Gimli, Keccak).
- **Word Length** It was a surprise for me to see that my software AES implementation is actually very bad, but anyway, it's a byte-oriented algorithm anyway. What I want to note here is that, Keccak-p[800,12] out-performed Keccak-p[1600,24] not because of smaller block size, but because the fewer number of rounds - using 32-bit words on a 64-bit machine is actually a drawback when compared with using native word lengths. It is for this reason, SHA-512 outperforms SHA-256 on 64-bit computers.

---

Side information:

Gimli had a full-rounds distinguishing attack last year: https://eprint.iacr.org/2020/744 . Gimli isn't the only 384-bit permutation though, Xoodoo is also a good 384-bit permutation, and is authored by the same group of people invented Keccak, but I haven't implemented in my suite for benchmarking yet.

Comment: @kelalaka Did it. But additional benchmarking statistics has to be provided by people using different HW. And it's sleep time in my timezone, and I can hardly keep my eyes open now.

Comment: It's okey. Have a nice sleep. HW is hard to do just for here as long as there are articles for a reference.

Comment: So, "Very Fast" is slower than "High"? You might want to reconsider the naming of those grades, it doesn't seem at all obvious on a glance what the relationship between "Fast" and "High" with or without the "Very" should be. After glancing at the table, I was going to write a comment asking if that "Very Fast" is the same as "Very High".

Answer (score 2):

You want a speed that's hard to reach even for a simple operation such as xoring the PRNG output with some data. You aren't going to get that speed for a CSPRNG except maybe with some serious dedicated hardware engineering.

But you don't need this! Sequential speed is not relevant for a PRNG with unspecified hardware. If you need more PRNG speed than your processor can deliver, run multiple instances in parallel, using as many processors as you need to achieve the desired speed. $N$ CSPRNG instances working in parallel, each instantiated with a seed that is itself obtained from a CSPRNG, constitute a CSPRNG with $N$ times the speed of each instance.

Answer (score 1):

The ChaCha20 cipher works at > 80 MiB/s on a single CPU core, so a modern GPU with hundreds or thousands of execution units would achieve the required performance of 100 Gbps. This is theoretically achieveable in a high-end desktop or server machine with the following setup:

1. CPU with at least 16 PCIe 4.0 lanes, 8 for the GPU, 8 for the network card (for a PCI throughput of 16 GB/s).
2. Either a software-based TCP/IP stack that can achieve 100 Gbps (not sure if it exists), or a hardware accelerated TCP/IP stack, or a hardware accelerated RDMA stack (not TCP/IP)

Some business-grade GPUs may also support peer-to-peer PCI transfers directly from GPU to network card and that works really smoothly with RDMA transfers.

Conceptually this setup is enough to support any kind of software-based branchless cipher that is designed for parallelism (unless there's some fundamental limitation that I couldn't think of). However things get much simpler with hardware-accelerated ciphers, like AES, because they might be 10 times faster and you can replace the GPU by a typical business-grade server with 50 to 500 cores. In this case, it just the CPU and the network card.

Both architectures seem to be achievable with common (high-end) hardware.